# Time-independent magnetic Schrodinger equation

Tags: spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics

Let $B$ be a magnetic field, let $\mathbf{a}$ be a vector and let $\Psi$ be the wave function. If $\mathcal{H}(B) = (-i\nabla + B\mathbf{a})^2$, where $\nabla$ is the gradient, then the *time-independent magnetic Schrodinger equation* is given by

$$\mathcal{H}(B) \Psi = \lambda \Psi$$

What is a simple way of finding the eigenvalue and eigenfunction solution to the above equation?

Comment: It is a very delicate issue. You can find many papers by Bernhard Helffer on the internet. Here is another source: http://www.mat.puc.cl/~graikov/noop.pdf

Comment: Are B and a constant or do they depend on coordinates?